# Hypertable and thrift installation on xampp on windows 10

Tags: hadoop, xampp, thrift, hypertable

Please tell me is it possible to install hypertable and thrift and also hadoop on xampp on windows 10 64bit to test a site.
If possible so please give step by step guide to install these things.
Regards

Comment: Besides being too broad, the whole question seems more appropriate on superuser IMHO.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I will ask it on superuser.